# Using string as parameter for function

Tags: c, string, function, parameters

I am trying to use a function with a string as a parameter. I am running into a couple of error messages. First, it says that string[i] is not an array, pointer, or vector, despite the fact that string is a character array. Secondly, it says that I am doing a pointer to integer conversion. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void example (char string) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        printf (string[i]);
    }
}

int main (void) {
    example("I like pie");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A Tutorial on strings in C: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm.

Comment: this line: void example (char string) {' says a single character is being passed.  perhaps you meant: 'void example (char*string) {'  <-- notice the parameter is now a pointer to char rather than a single character.  That char being pointed to could easily just be the addres of the first character in a 'string' of characters.

Comment: this line: 'printf (string[i]);' does not have a valid format string as the first parameter.  so either write: printf( "%c", string[i] ).  or write: putc( string[i] ;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void example(char string)` should be `void example(char *string)`. You declared it to take a character, you want it to take a character pointer or array.

Also, you need to tell `printf` you are giving it a character: `printf("%c", string[i]);`.

Answer (score 4):

Your API is wrong it should be

```
void example (char *string) { // string is a pointer 
    int i;
    size_t n = strlen(string);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("%c",string[i]); // print character using %c
    }
}
```

Calculate the string length before the loop , calling strlen() in each iteration is not a good idea.

PS: what `string` points to is read-only you can't modify it

Answer (score 0):

You should use `void example(char *string)` instead of `void example (char string)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void example (char *string) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
    printf ("%c",string[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main (void) {
   example("I like pie");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function ***example*** just receives a character. To get a string you can use a pointer. Also you can use "***%s***" format specifier in printf instead of using the ***for*** loop and ***strlen()*** function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void example (char *string) {
    int i;
    printf ("%s\n",string);

}
```